# How to set int equal to a int pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, transpose

Hey I have this code that transposes an array and I am having some problems setting an temp value int to the int pointer.

```
void transpose(array_t a) {

    printf("how about here\n");
    long i;
    long k;
    int *i1 = &a[i][0];
    int *j1 = &a[0][k];
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 0;
    printf("This number is %d\n",*i1);
    printf("This letter j is %d\n",*j1);
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            for (k = 0; k < i; ++k) {
            t1 = *i1;
            t2 = *j1;
            printf("What is t1 %d\n",t1);
            i1 = t2;
            j1 = t1;
            i1 += 8;
            j1 += 32;
            }
    }
```

}

Whenever I try to enter the loop I'll get a seg fault and when I change it to t1 = &i1 I just get memory addresses and I have no idea how to get the actual int. In the end of the loop there is my idea of shifting l1 and j1 to the next part of the array.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Also for the inner loop I am following this assembly code language to try and solve it
.L3:
movq(%rax), %rcx
movq(%rdx), %rsi
movq%rsi, (%rax)
movq%rcx, (%rdx)
addq$8, %rax
addq$32, %rdx
cmpq%r9, %rax
jne.L3
so any questions about my logic can be seen there :-)

Comment: In `int *i1 = &a[i][0];` and `int *j1 = &a[0][k];` the `i` and `k` are do not have a value set, so the behaviour is *undefined*. The pointers are set to effectively random values and dereferencing them can cause a seg fault.

Comment: Alright yeah that fixed some stuff! Im getting the numbers I want to be getting but do you have any idea about the pointer arithmetic that I tried to implement?

Comment: Yes, pointer arithmetic considers the size of the type being pointed too. So `pointer + 1` points to the next array element, whether 32-bit or 8. And `i1 + 8` indexes the 8th array element from the one that `i1` points to. It works like array indexing: the second element of an `int` array is at `array[1]` not `array[4]`.

Comment: Okay I am getting that I am still getting some incorrect numbers for my array and it looks like i and j are going up by 4 and not by the actual amount that should be in the array but I think I can maybe handle it, though any further help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If they are supposed to be stepping through consecutive array elements you should add `1` to the pointer.

Comment: Well one should be going through consecutive array element but then one should be going to the next column which I am assuming would be pointer + 4?

Comment: What is t1 1
What is t2 1
What is t1 0
What is t2 0
What is t1 2
What is t2 2
What is t1 0
What is t2 0
What is t1 3
What is t2 3
What is t1 0
What is t2 0
My problem is that its printing out stuff like this which are not elements of the array ( array elements should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)

Comment: @WeatherVane my bad...I missed that comment earlier.

Comment: It has now become unclear what is being asked...

Comment: Sorry so I input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16 into the array and I am suppose to transpose it so itll appear as 1,5,9,13,2,6,10,14,3,7,11,15,4,8,12,16 and I am trying to do this while also following the assembly instructions from the comment above. The problem is though that my t1 and t2 keep receiving values that aren't in the array and I am not sure why.

Comment: Is there a question here?  The code doesn't appear to bear any relation to what you way you are trying to do.